# Picard's Iteration -- direct proof of convergence of sequence of integrals to $\tan x$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The extra credit question on one of the midterm exams for the online version of MIT's Honor's Differential Equations asks us to directly solve the IVP $y' = 1 + y^2$, $y(0) = 0$ and then show that the limit of the functions $y_{n+1} = \int y_n(s)ds$ as $n \to \infty$ is the same.  The first part is trivial:  $y = \tan x$.  However, the second part seems tougher.  It's not hard to calculate the first few iterations:
\begin{align}
y_0 &= 0\\
y_1 &= t\\
y_2 &= t + \frac{t^3}{3}\\
y_3 &= t + \frac{t^3}{3} + \frac{2t^5}{15} + \frac{t^7}{63}\\
\vdots
\end{align}
And we can write out (the beginning of) a Maclaurin expansion for $\tan t$:
\begin{align}
\tan t & = t + \frac{t^3}{3} + \frac{2t^5}{15} + \frac{17t^7}{315} + \cdots
\end{align}
This is, of course, suggestive.  But I see no obvious way to demonstrate that the $y_n$ will approach the latter polynomial as $n \to \infty$.

**Edit:**  Overnight reflection brought me to a possible solution, but I'm not particularly confident in it.  I would appreciate confirmation that what I do below makes sense--in particular, I'd appreciate confirmation that my reasoning is not circular.

We note that the Maclaurin expansion for $\tan x$ is $x + R_1$, where $R$ is a polynomial of degree $> 1$.  Since $y = \tan x$ is a solution of our original ODE, we have
    \begin{align}
  \tan ' x & = 1 + \tan^2x\Rightarrow\\
  \tan x & = \int (1 + \tan^2x)dx\\
  & = \int [1 + (x + R_1)^2]dx\\
  & = \int (1 + x^2 + 2xR_1 + R_1^2)dx\\
  & = x + \frac{x^3}{3} + \int (2xR_1 + R_1^2)dx
 \end{align}
        Note that $2xR_1 + R_1^2$ is a polynomial of degree of at least $3$, so the last term of the sum above is a polynomial of degree at least $4$.  Call this polynomial $R_2$.  So we have
    \begin{align}
  \tan x = x + \frac{x^3}{3} + R_2
 \end{align}
        We now repeat the process:
    \begin{align}
  \tan x & = \int \left[1 + \left(x + \frac{x^3}{3} + R_2\right)^2\right]dx\\
  & = \int \left[1 + x^2 + \frac{2x^4}{3} + \frac{x^6}{9} + R_2p(x)\right]dx
 \end{align} 
        where $p(x)$ is some polynomial in $x$.  Then we have
        \begin{align}
  \tan x & = x + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{2x^5}{15} + \frac{x^7}{63} + \int R_2p(x)dx
  \end{align}
        $\int R_3p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree of degree at least $7$; call it $R_4$.  Continuing to iterate in this way, we see that we are, in fact, repeating precisely the calculations we would make for our original Picard iteration.  So $\tan x = \lim_{n \to \infty} y_n$.