# Picard iterations converge to solution on interval of existence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In question 5 of [this](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-034-honors-differential-equations-spring-2009/exams/MIT18_034s09_exam02_midterm02.pdf) MIT midterm they discuss the inital value problem
$$y'=1+y^2, \quad y(0)=0. $$
The exact solution is $y(t)=\tan(t)$, which is defined on the interval $t \in(- \pi/2,\pi/2)$. The sequence of Picard iterations are defined by
$$y_n(t)=\begin{cases} 0 & n=0, \\ \int_0^t \left(1+y_{n-1}^2(\tau) \right) \mathrm{d} \tau & n \geqslant 1. \end{cases} $$
The first few of them are 
$$\begin{align}
y_0(t)&= 0, \\ y_1(t)&=t, \\y_2(t) &=\frac{t^3}{3}+t, \\ y_3(t)&=\frac{t^{15}}{59535}+\frac{4 t^{13}}{12285}+\frac{134 t^{11}}{51975}+\frac{38 t^9}{2835}+\frac{17 t^7}{315}+\frac{2 t^5}{15}+\frac{t^3}{3}+t.
\end{align} $$

Part (c) asks to

> show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n(t)=y(t)$.

The intention is probably to show that $y_n \to y$ in some neighborhood of $0$, which can be easily done using the Picard-Lindelöf theorem: Over the set
$$\{(t,y):|t| \leqslant a, |y| \leqslant b \}  $$
the right hand side has the maximum value $1+b^2$. Hence the solution exists for $$|t| < \min\left( a, \frac{b}{1+b^2} \right).$$
We get a maximal interval by choosing $b=1$. This means that $y_n(t) \to y(t)$ for $t \in (-1/2,1/2)$. However, can we do better? Is there a way to show that $y_n(t) \to y(t)=\tan(t)$ for all $t \in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$?

Thank you!

Comment: Part (c) asks for $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} y_n(t) = y(t)$

Comment: @jcandy corrected, thanks.

Comment: I noticed this, too: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844146/picards-iteration-direct-proof-of-convergence-of-sequence-of-integrals-to?rq=1